# Facebook graph api converted to Fql with "where"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have this api req. Which groups the questions from the page with the name's of voted users ; user id .... etc

```
367298846687999?fields=questions.fields(id,created_time,question,options.fields(name,votes.fields(id,username),vote_count,from))
```

But it returns all questions on the page.

I need to get the questions by selecting date of creation. Like 
`Month(created_time) = 4` and `year(created_time) = 2012`

It seem I need fql but there is nothing about getting the questions from the page by page id.

Can we convert the api code that I put to be `fql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the FQL

SELECT id,owner,question,created_time FROM question WHERE owner=367298846687999

To limit the questions to only those asked in April 2012 you need to add `AND created_time >= 2012-04-01 AND created_time <= 2012-04-30` to your query.

To get the options and votes, you'll need to construct a multiquery where you pass the result of the first query to the subsequent queries to get the information from the `question_option` table, and then those results to get the `question_option_votes`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can order by created_time in fql, but created_time in fb db not separate by year and month. Fb combined year,month,day, and time together in timestamp format. So,u need to convert your normal date time into timestamp format then i will solve your problem by using fql.